# How to cross compile from windows g++ cygwin to get linux executable file 

Tags: c++, linux, cygwin, cross-compiling, codeblocks

I have an updated cygwin-full install ,mingw ,codeblocks on a windows system. 
i have a c++ program which performs xml generation based on input.

I understand to build an executable file for unix we use makefiles. makefiles being typical project files .
Hence i used the plugin cbp2make.exe to get the makefile for the cbp project file. and i tried to execute make in cygwin. hoping to get a linux executable file. but this was clearly wrong.

a typical test c++ test program `test.c` would be compiled in cygwin using gcc cross compile options like.

```
g++-linux -o test test.c
```

this would give us the linux executable file test or if no name is specified it would give an a.out

This is all well and good for a simple c++ program with no included header files.

I understand when we are dealing with c++ files with lot of external library files a simple `g++ -o ourprojfile.exe ourprojectfile.cpp` does not work hence we would need to use make files. **Question 1 : Am i wrong in assuming this ?***

**Question 2: how can we setup cross compile to get a linux executable file directly from codeblocks.**

---

Update : the problem at my end seems to be missing dependent cpp files which i assumed i included in the main file.
The solution was to include them in the main file or simply write handle like so

```
g++-linux myprog_linux main.cpp first.cpp second.cpp third.cpp
```

The problem now is after i get the Linux executable file. 
when i try to run it on linux machine i get the error of a

```
 /usr/local/folder/myfile/my_prog_nix: error while loading shared libraries: 
libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

what sort of linking do i need to do clear this?

Comment: Cross-compiling is quite tricky and troublesome. Since you are just targetting linux it'd be easier to just install linux and compile on it. You could just a virtual machine to install linux as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong assuming that you need makefile. Any builder will do. The important point is, that you have to tell the builder to:

- Call `g++linux` instead of `g++` (or `mingw-g++` or whatever it's calling)
- Set proper path to look for includes and libraries. The compiler will know where to look up system libraries that came with it on it's own, so you just have to deal with any extra stuff you have.

Normally makefiles call the compiler given in `CC` for C sources and `CXX` for C++ sources and passes them content of `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` as additional arguments respectively. But you can probably just tell CodeBlocks (but I never used it, so I don't know) to call different compiler and avoid all the make business.

Comment: Ok.So the problem is with setting the proper path to look for included libraries . Can you post example code on how this can be done? if we have say one test.c file and its corresponding test.h file.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the GCC cross-compiler for Cygwin installed in Cygwin:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/metamod-p/files/

untar into Cygwin root, then compile from Cygwin using:
g++-linux
or
g++-linux-x86_64

Comment: cool! if it is really working :-)

Comment: **-1** As i have already mentioned in the post i do have it installed that is how i already am compiling the normal test file. Your answer is not relevant or helpful.If we do this to the main.cpp file which has included header files this gives  undeclared type erros in g++-linux and in g++ gives not declared in this scope type errors.

Answer (score 1):

In order to cross-compile you have to get (or build) custom assembly of gcc, with linux code generator. Since it's not a trivial task it's better just to move sources to linux machine and do a native build there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong compiler if you want to build for UNIX from windows.
mingw-w64 has an ubuntu-natty target compiler (11.04,  and 64-bit ) and a BSD target compiler

if you want to compile with your host as windows x64 and your target as these 2 OS's with 2 flavors of processors as a target, you want mingw-w64, personal builds, vityan.

the mingw-w64 project is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ (Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org i suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org))

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20NonWin/vityan/

you should have a sourceforge account before downloading probably (you might be able to change the https to an http maybe).

cygwin is UNIX tools ported to windows and the compiler I think is actually from mingw-w64 in the automated builds area.
cygwin is windows target.  its purpose is to provide a UNIX-like environment for windows for developers.

Answer (score 0):

> > untar into Cygwin root, then compile from Cygwin using: g++-linux or g++-linux-x86_64

Actually you must rename /bin/g++-linux-4.1 and /bin/gcc-linux-4.1

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment to an existing answer...